# Make my turtle get bigger when it meets another turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to figure this out, how to make my turtle get bigger and bigger if the turtle player meets turtle food. I can only make it bigger 1 time but then it won't get any bigger. What do you think I should do?

```
i = 0
io = i + 1

if player.is_collision(food):
        x = random.randint(-250, 250)
        y = random.randint(-250, 250)
        food.goto(x,y)
        player.shapesize(io)
        player.shapesize()
```

When I try use this:

```
io = i += 1
```

this code won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
io = i += 1
```

isn't valid Python code, instead you can do:

```
io = io + 1
```

or

```
io += 1
```

Something like:

```
io = 1

if player.is_collision(food):
    x = random.randint(-250, 250)
    y = random.randint(-250, 250)
    food.goto(x, y)
    io = io + 1
    player.shapesize(io)
```